# Static IP clears itself Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip-address, static-ip

I have to set a static IP to access the internet while I am at my work office.

I usually go through the more visual of the two ways [listed as answers here](https://superuser.com/questions/312802/how-can-i-force-a-static-ip-in-windows-7). Though that could change now that I know there is a cmd way to accomplish this.

My question is: *Sometimes* after my IP has been set while working all day I shut down at night, come back the next day and it has erased the IP address and Subnet mask. So I have to re-enter both of those before I can access the internet.

What could cause it to forget the IP I give it and is this behavior intended?

**EDIT:** Images

When I set it:

[image: when I set it]

Upon arrival and boot up next day:

[image]

Comment: If it is really set to static it wouldn't be able to change, specially automatically as you said. Check if you are using the "Use the folowing IP Address" on your Windows IP settings.

Comment: yes, I have to check the radio button that says "Use the following IP address" in order to be able to type mine in. I suppose I chose poor wording, it doesn't change so much as it just clears itself out.

Comment: @Tim: Do you mean it reverts back to DHCP?

Comment: A print-screen of your setting here would be nice....

Comment: nope it stays set to static but forgets the IP and subnet mask that I typed in. adding screenshot.

Comment: @Tim Does your IP address don't belongs to private range 169.254.0.1 to 169.254.255.254? [reference](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/protocolsdhcp/g/bldef_apipa.htm)

Comment: I suspect there is a policy being applied to your machine at work via Group Policy or similar that is going wrong.  Have you checked with your work tech people?

Comment: I am the work tech people for the most part =x. I don't think it does it every day either, sometimes I come back and it is still fine. Could my messup have been caused because when I take the laptop home and want to use it there I do have to switch back to auto assign IP (I do this occasionaly, but note that my question is about times when I do not change this setting).

Comment: Is this a wireless or wired connection?

Comment: It is a wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both parts to '*Obtain an IP/DNS server adress automatically*'. After that another tab would appear named '*Alternate configuration*'. Put all your static settings there and be sure to reboot your machine.

Comment: I went to try this and found out that I actually had already set this alternate configuration a while back. For some reason even with it set the PC is still trying to use DHCP while I am at work. Because of this it is unable to connect to the internet until I re-enter the static IP as the 'primary' configuration.